# Print ion monkey generated code

Tags: v8, compiler-optimization, spidermonkey

Is there any way to dump dissasembly of genrated code for each ion (LIR) instruction.
Something similar --print-opt-code --code-comments in v8?

Answer (score 0):

`IONFLAGS=codegen js --ion-offthread-compile=off app.js`

You need debug build of spidermonkey. After running this you'll have code generator log in stderr.
In order to find specific function search log for "Emitting code for script".